# Checkout code using jenkins pipeline and build that on any available nodes/agents

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to checkout the code at a particular location (ex. *C:\scm\*) on windows using jenkins pipeline (jenkinsfile) and want to execute the build from the checkout location (*C:\scm\*) in any available nodes/agents at that particular time.

Can you please provide any leads? (Was able to do on linux machine)

Something like below:-

```
node ('win1')

{

stage ('checkout')

..........

}


node ('win2')

{

stage ('build')

........

}
```

My requirement is I should checkout my code at particular location (master jenkins) whenever my job is triggered and able to build it on any available node at that particular time rather than building it on the master jenkins only (require this to not overload the jenkins master)

Comment: Sorry think you need to be more precise on what you want and esp. what you already tried.

Comment: As @JoergS mentioned, we need to see more code than a bunch of dot lines to determine what could be causing the issue since you were able to run it on Linux. Also, any particular reason why are you using a scripted pipeline than declarative, just out of curiosity?

Comment: my requirement is :- I will checkout my code on the jenkins master (STAGE 1) and should able to run the other steps (i.e. buid) on the available node(agent) (STAGE 2)

Comment: using scripted as need to add some custom method :)

Comment: Why do you wish to build in the same location ?? cant you build in the workspace and push it back to the location that you want ??

Comment: where did I said that I want to build it on the same location! My requirement is I should checkout my code at particular location (master jenkins) whenever my job is triggered and able to build it on any available node at that particular time rather than building it on the master jenkins only (require this to not overload the jenkins master)

Comment: @Gaurav So what do you want to achieve is how to use pipeline syntax to check the source code to another directory and build it? And did you tried to generate pipeline script here http://localhost:1080/job/pipeline/pipeline-syntax/?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yeah I tried using the stash/unstash, but not able to execute that, so need some insights.

Comment: What were your problems with using stashing? That would be the usual way to achieve such functionality.

Comment: @Torbilicious I am getting "ERROR: No files included in stash" and not able to find the solution.

Comment: Well that simply means that there were no files found to be stashed. Maybe you misconfigured your glob parameter?